# Error Page Directive in web.xml not working

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml, custom-error-pages

I am trying to simply get my default error page to display when an error occurs. I have tried every configuration I can think of, but I just can't get it to work. When I navigate directly to the error page it works, but errors will not direct there (in the native Eclipse browser or any mainstream browser).

There are no errors in the DD.

Here is how I currently have the DD:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.GetUser</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetUser.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
   <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <jsp-config>
   <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>Functions</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/functions.tld</taglib-location>
   </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
  <error-page>
   <location>/MyApp/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/MyApp/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>429</error-code>
   <location>/MyApp/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
   <location>/MyApp/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

(I'm specifying 429 because the API I am working with has been throwing those to me recently)

Here is the error page:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isErrorPage="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>You blew it</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You caused a ${pageContext.exception} exception</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If it helps, here is the 429 error, and subsequent IOException error log I am getting (not looking to solve this here, just in case it helps).

```html
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL: https://dpu-ten-web.api-connect.com/api/rest/user
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at com.example.web.GetUser.doPost(GetUser.java:93)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL: https://dpu-ten-web.api-connect.com/api/rest/user
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
 at com.example.web.GetUser.doPost(GetUser.java:86)
 ... 24 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you set error by calling `setStatus` method? If so try to set error by calling `sendError`.